# React custom onClick event with parameter

Tags: react-native, react-redux, reactjs

I'd like to have a custom onClick event fired any time one of my  is selected, however I can't get the step.id to be passed properly. `stepId` is undefined when I try to dispatch `requestStep`. Any thoughts?

```
var requestStepOnEnter = ({ stepId }) => {
  store.dispatch(requestStep(stepId));
};

const ExperimentDetail = ({ steps }) => (
  <div className="experiment-detail">
    {
      steps.map(step =>
        <NavItem
         eventKey={step.order}
         key={step.id}
         onClick= {() => requestStepOnEnter(stepId)}>
         {step.order}
        </NavItem>
      )
    }
  </div>
);

export default ExperimentDetail;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var requestStepOnEnter = ({ stepId }) => {
  store.dispatch(requestStep(stepId));
};
```

to

```
var requestStepOnEnter = (stepId) => {
  store.dispatch(requestStep(stepId));
};
```

because you aren't passing an object, so the signature is wrong. Alternatively, pass `stepId` in an object:

```
onClick= {() => requestStepOnEnter({ stepId })}>
```

```js
const test = ({ prop }) => console.log('The value of prop?' , prop);

test({ prop: 'works' });

test('doesnt work');
```

Another problem would be that you're calling `requestStepOnEnter` with the argument `stepId` which is `undefined`. The correct should be `step.id`

---

**Here is a working suggestion**

```
var requestStepOnEnter = (stepId) => {
  store.dispatch(requestStep(stepId));
};

const ExperimentDetail = ({ steps }) => (
  <div className="experiment-detail">
    {
      steps.map(step =>
        <NavItem
         eventKey={step.order}
         key={step.id}
         onClick= {() => requestStepOnEnter(step.id)}>
         {step.order}
        </NavItem>
      )
    }
  </div>
);

export default ExperimentDetail;
```